# MySQL IF Function not recognizing characters with integers

Tags: mysql

The issue I am having is that the IF function in MySQL is not correctly telling me if an ID is or is not located in the second table. Here is where you can view what I am doing

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/501513/4'

```
SELECT c.id AS clientID, IF (e.id, 'yes', 'no') AS hasID
FROM Table1 c LEFT JOIN Table2 e ON (c.id = e.id)
WHERE c.id IN ("123456","H100512","94061","OW59556","OR37615");
```

If you notice that the values "H100512" and "w76789" should both say 'yes' and not 'no' because they are found in the second table. I notice that if I take away the letter from the id in the query and in the table then it will correctly say whether it is there present in the table or not. Am I doing something wrong in the IF Function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a matter of course, I think it is better to declare the `id`s as `varchar()` and to use single quotes rather than double quotes to delimit character strings.  However, neither of these is the cause of your problem.

The problem is the statement:

```
if(e.id, 'yes', 'no')
```

In MySQL, this is checking:

```
if(e.id <> 0, 'yes', 'no')
```

You are probably thinking that it is checking for `NULL`.  Nope.  So, what is happening is that a string like `'H100512'` is being converted to an integer -- and it gets converted to `0` which fails the test.

I think you should write the query as:

```
SELECT c.id AS clientID,
       (case when e.id is not null then 'yes' else 'no' end) AS hasID
FROM Table1 c LEFT JOIN
     Table2 e
     ON c.id = e.id
WHERE c.id IN ('123456', 'H100512', '94061', 'OW59556', 'OR37615', 'w76789');
```

This is explicit in what it is doing and it uses the ANSI standard conditional statement.

Comment: That is exactly what I was thinking. That it was checking for NULL. I didn't stop and think that it could possibly be converting to an integer. Thank you for the answer. The Case statement worked! You explained it perfectly. Thank you!